# Perl Regexp interpolating

Tags: regex, perl, interpolation

I have some code:

```
$a = 'abcdef';
$b = 'f\1d';
$a =~ s/d(e)f/$b/g;
print $a;
```

I get `abcf\1d`, but how can I get `abcfed`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$a = 'abcdef';
$b = '"f$1d"';
$a =~ s/d(e)f/$b/gee;
print $a;
```

Notice that there are two `e` modifiers in `/gee`; the second one evaluates `"f$1d"` string to `fed`.

As a side note you don't need `/g` as you're replacing only one pattern occurrence.

Comment: Why do I need to write `'"f${1}d"'`? Why does `'f${1}d'` return error?

Comment: @user23791 there is an error as `f${1}d` is not valid perl code, and you're asking perl to interpret it like one.

Comment: But why does `$b = 'f${1}d'; $a =~ s/d(e)f/"$b"/gee;` return error?

Comment: @user23791 for the same reason `foo bar` doesn't pass perl compilation, and `"foo bar"` does. And mentioned string MUST be valid perl code.

Comment: There's no need for the braces. `1d` isn't a valid identifier, so Perl disambiguates properly and `my $b = '"f$1d"'` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

`$a` and `$b` are special variables, used for `sort`. So you shoulnd't use them at all.

Better solution is to use another variable and then:

```
$var_a = 'abcdef';
$var_b = '"f${1}d"';
$var_a =~ s/d(e)f/$var_b/gee;
print $var_a;
```

The trick is to say, that the substitution uses the `\1` first found var ( use the `/e` flag to avoid using `\1` :P )